# Extract one property as a List<String> from a ICollection of a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to select a single property [filename] into a List out of a ICollection where dr405 has many properties.

`return GetDR405ById(c, id).dr405files.Select(p => p.FileName).ToList<String>();`

```
     public class dr405files
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public String TangiblePropertyId { get; set; }
    public String FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime?  UploadDate { get; set; }
    public Byte[] FileData {get;set;}
    public long? FileLength { get; set; }


}
```

I want the SQL equivalent of `SELECT [Column1] FROM [Table1]` as opposed to `SELECT * FROM [Table1]

Comment: The code you've got will already do what you're asking for. What's the problem?

Comment: What does GetDR405ById() method return?

Comment: @JoeWhite The problem is it's not working as expected.  I was hoping when I posted this question that someone would say exactly what you said.  Now I can review my other methods to find out why that statement always returns 0 records.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you just want to do

```
return GetDR405ById(c, id).Select(p => p.FileName).ToList();
```

unless `GetDR405ById` really does return an object that has a property called dr405files that is a generic collection of dr405files objects.

EDIT.

Notice i have also removed the generic type param from ToList().  Filename is a string so T will be infered by the compiler.